# What is opposite of strrchr function?

Tags: php, strrchr

I want to remove all characters after last specific string.
For this function I need opposite of `strrchr` function.

For example, I want to remove all characters after last "." from "Hello.World.pdf".  But with `strrchr` function I can only remove "Hello.World" before "."!

I want something like this code:

```
<?php
echo strrchr("Hello.World.pdf" , "." , true);
?>
```

But this code isn't working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing with file names that can have various extensions and you would like to remove the extension, you can get the extension using `pathinfo()` and then use `str_replace()` to get rid of it:

```
$filename  = 'Hello.World.pdf';
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filename  = str_replace('.' . $extension, '', $filename);
echo $filename; //Hello.World
```

More info on [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) and [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
echo substr('Hello.World.pdf', 0, strrpos('Hello.World.pdf', '.'));
```

Reading material:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Note:
I recommend you verify that strrpos actualy returns a valid value.

EDIT:

```
$haystack = 'Hello.World.pdf';
$needle = '.';
$pos = strrpos($haystack, $needle);

echo ($pos === false ? $haystack : substr($haystack, 0, $pos));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're interested in filenames and extensions; *junkstu* almost had it, but you can just use `PATHINFO_FILENAME` to get the filename without the extension:

```
echo pathinfo("Hello.World.pdf", PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Comment: Yes, much cleaner solution, especially if the extension is of no interest